# When loading image from storage app crashes

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to load an image from storage, but the app crashes and gives me this error:

```
12-06 22:08:41.539: E/AndroidRuntime(28957): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:  No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW  dat=file://android.graphics.Bitmap@429af028file:///storage/emulated/0/My Folder/1417896511752.jpg }
12-06 22:08:41.539: E/AndroidRuntime(28957):    at  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1660)
12-06 22:08:41.539: E/AndroidRuntime(28957):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
```

This is my code I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + bitmap + fileUri), null);
                startActivity(intent);
            return;
          }
      });
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here,  as the intent does work if i remove `Uri.parse` before `("file.....);

Could any one help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + bitmap + fileUri), null);
```

to

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + bitmap + fileUri),  "image/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have activity that handles your intent
try this instead.

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  it's not crashing now, however nothing happens.  there is no errors or anything?

Comment: it's not displaying the image.

Comment: it doesn't display image because you have not activity(application) that handles your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have activity, that is what the error is saying. Maybe you can check for an activity before calling `startActivity()`.

Also, are you sure it works when you remove `Uri.parse`? Because it should not as setDataAndType expects a URI as data and not a String so it should be an error.